# publishing my react-app bundled in electron app to github releases

Tags: reactjs, electron, github-release

I have a `create-react-app` which I have bundled with `electron` and I have packaged it  but now I want to publish my app so I tried using Github releases but then as per their documentation when I try to attach my files it fails saying that I cannot upload file more than 10 mb.

I was unable to find any workaround or solution for this so any help on this will be highly appreciated.

I am unable to perform other alternatives as I do not know docker so any ideas or views on this..

Thanking you in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [@octokit/rest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@octokit/rest) package. It's a convenient way to use the GitHub REST APIs to automatically upload your app releases to your GitHub releases. I have been using it and haven't had an issue with 10 MB limits.

Electron uses it to publish their artifacts to their releases, and they definitely have files greater than 10 MB. See how they use it [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/66846bff975f92dd721d5ca29f332edf3795f1c0/script/upload-to-github.js). As a security recommendation, make sure you do not check in your GitHub personal token in your code. Instead, have it injected to your environment variables by your CI solution when doing release builds.

Comment: Thanks for the code but I wanted to know How and where to define process.argv

Comment: I am getting this error Error uploading Dhaval App-1.0.0.dmg to GitHub, will retry.  Error was: { HttpError: Empty value for parameter 'file': undefined